# How to plot average ROC and AUC in Python?

Tags: python, roc, auc

I need to perform a classification of users using binary classification (User 1 or 0 in each case).

I have 30 users and there are 30 sets of FPR and TPR.

I did not use `roc_curve(y_test.ravel(), y_score.ravel())` to get FPR and TPF (there is a reason for this which I have to classify each of them using binary classification and generate FPR Aand TPF using my own code).

Actually, my setting was I did not store class labels as multi-class. What I did was I take one user as a positive class and the rest as negative class. I repeated for all other users. Then I calculated FPR and TPF using my own code without using  `roc_auc_score`.

Let say I already have the values of FPR and TPF in alist.

I have these codes:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interp

n_classes=30

# First aggregate all false positive rates
all_fpr = np.unique(np.concatenate([fpr_svc[i] for i in range(n_classes)])) # Classified using SVC

# Then interpolate all ROC curves at this points
mean_tpr = np.zeros_like(all_fpr)
for i in range(n_classes):
    mean_tpr += interp(all_fpr, fpr_svc[i], tpr_svc[i])

# Finally average it and compute AUC
mean_tpr /= n_classes

fpr = all_fpr[:]
tpr = mean_tpr[:]

plt.figure()
lw = 2
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, color='darkorange',
         lw=lw)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=lw, linestyle='--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Acceptance Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Acceptance Rate')
plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic example')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

But, it produced this figure which is look weird.
[image]

Moreover, how do I get the average AUC as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your setting, but in general you can compute the average AUC for a multi-class classifier using `sklearn`s `roc_auc_score`. If by *average* you mean to compare each class with every other class use `ovo` (One vs. One). Otherwise, if you prefer to compare each class to all the others together, use `ovr` (One vs. Rest). Here's the documentation for the `multi_class` param:

> **multi_class *{‘raise’, ‘ovr’, ‘ovo’}, default=’raise’***
>
> Multiclass only. Determines the type of configuration to use. The default value raises
>   an error, so either `ovr` or `ovo` must be passed explicitly.
>
> `'ovr'`: Computes the AUC of each class against the rest [3] [4]. This
>   treats the multiclass case in the same way as the multilabel case.
>   Sensitive to class imbalance even when `average == 'macro'`, because
>   class imbalance affects the composition of each of the ‘rest’
>   groupings.
>
> `'ovo'`: Computes the average AUC of all possible pairwise combinations
>   of classes [5]. Insensitive to class imbalance when `average ==
>   'macro'`.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.htm

Comment: Actually, my setting was I did not store class label as multi-class. What I did was I take one user as a positive class and the rest as negative class. I repeated for all other users. Then I calculated FPR and TPF using my own code without using  roc_auc_score.

Comment: Sounds like OVR.

Comment: Anyhow, if you already computed TPR and FPR, why not just integrate? E.g. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html#integrating-using-samples